# RIA Services extending code-generated entity model partial classes

Tags: .net, silverlight, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I'm writing an application that has POCO Entity Framework data access on the server. When RIA services creates the model in Silverlight, it generates a (let's call it) "RIA Services" model. That is, it's not just a copy of my POCOs. These classes in the model, to begin with, are sealed, and for instance expose Lists as EntityCollections.

Since they are sealed, I cannot extend them to (say) provide extra functionality (that doesn't belong in the server), or implement an interface.

I can, however, extend the functionality of these classes by implementing the defined partial methods, and adding extra properties to the *other* partial class.

Is doing so generally discouraged. Is it some kind of code smell? Is there a good reason why I *shouldn't* do this?

Comment: Nope... transitioning to it, but not at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `partial` implementations frequently but I don't find it to be code smell. In fact, I think it is a lot better than wrapping them with more code. At that point, you might as well skip RIA and write your own WCF change tracker... but I digress.

If you want a rich domain model, then `partial` implementations are one great way to accomplish that. The default code generator creates partial methods for the most meaningful points in a WCF RIA entity's life cycle. By implementing these partials, you move away from the [Anemic Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/tags/domain%20driven%20design.html).

As you stated above, you can implement an interface and create your own methods and properties. IOW you are not limited to implementing the `partial` stubs. If all else fails, [modify the default code generator](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/10/28/RiaServicesT4WalkUp.aspx) to your liking. I did to remove `sealed` from every entity to make testing easier.

**UPDATE:** Here is my code to remove `sealed`

```
[DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator(typeof (CustomClientCodeGenerator), "C#")]
public class CustomClientCodeGenerator : CSharpClientCodeGenerator
{
    private EntityGenerator _entityGenerator;

    protected override EntityGenerator EntityGenerator
    {
        get { return _entityGenerator ?? (_entityGenerator = new CustomEntityGenerator()); }
    }

    private class CustomEntityGenerator : CSharpEntityGenerator
    {
        public override string TransformText()
        {
            return base.TransformText().Replace("sealed ", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```